# Sentence (if he didn't..... and if he doesn't......)

Tags: sentence

> She is threatening to report him to the police station if he didn't
> give back her mobile.

> She is threatening to report him to the police station if he
> doesn't give back her mobile.

Which one is correct

Comment: Which one do you think is correct? Explain your doubts. Your question may do better on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). See also the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: "if he didn't give back her mobile". is it correct? as a hypothetical situation.

Answer (score -1):

The latter. The first one mixes present tense and past tense. The latter used both present tense.

Comment: Separate clauses: If I ate before dinner, and I eat dessert, too, will I have an appetite for my midnight snack? Same: I never lied and will not now.